# How to pass variables from variables.py as a global value

Tags: python, variables

Question, A friend of mine recommended:

> just make a "variables.py". put a dict in there then on your code, do
> import variables and then variables.mydict because it direcets it to
> the GIL namespace and it'll be shard across all

I tried to follow his tip and I did something simple as:

first.py

```py
def function():
    out_file = dict()
    return out_file
```

second.py

```py
import first

val = first.function()
print(val) #first run should be empty, next run after restarting the script it should print "hello" ?
val["testing"] = "hello"
print(val)
```

**Expected result:**

> First run should be {} and then "{'testing': 'hello'}" Next time I run
> the script again (Closing second.py and then re-open it again) should
> print: "{'testing': 'hello'}" and "{'testing': 'hello'}" again because
> of the two prints

**Actual result:**

> It starts by printing {} and then "{'testing': 'hello'}" and if I
> re-launch the script it prints out the same "{'testing': 'hello'}" -
> Like the variable doesn't get saved somehow?

Shouldn't the first run when I run it be empty then on next run if I run the script again it should be "hello"?

Comment: Could you clarify? are you running it two seperate times, the first of which getting {} and then {'testing':'hello'}, and on the second one getting the same thing again (starting with the {})? Are you running the program once and then once it finishes, running it again, or are you just doing the same code in the program twice?

Comment: Ah sorry, Yes. What I am doing is that I run the program once and then once its finished. I run it again. @Shufi123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comment you left, your problem is this - whenever the program stops running any variable created will delete itself (It won't ever stay). Although you're importing another file, that does nothing in relation to the saving of the variables. If you need to save the values themselves (and since you're using dictionaries) I would advies you look into the Json module in Python. It allows you to save data to a file and then later load the data.

Comment: Ahhhh right. In that case it would be alot better to save it into a data in that case etc?

Comment: Depends on what you specifically need, but basically, yes.

Comment: Well the idea is to run different scripts, etc second.py, third.py, fourth.py etc etc and that they all share the same variable value so that they all share the same value, if that make sense?

Comment: Yes. Just look into the Json module and you'll see how to save to files and then be able to load the values while running each individual file.